# Filling empty vector with values of another vector given similar (not the same) values

Tags: r, vector

I have three vectors:

```
x1 <- c(0.000, 0.792, 1.451, 1.802, 2.551, 2.591, 3.991, 4.321)
x2 <- c(0.8, 2.6)
x3 <- c(3,6,-1)
```

I want to create another vector (`x4`) that is the same length as `x1` and populated with the values from `x3`, but `3`s become `6`s and `6`s become `-1`s when the values in `x2` are very close to `x1`, but not necessarily if they are the same. Then, `x4` would look like this:

```
   x1  x4
0.000   3
0.792   3 #0.8 in x2 is close to 0.792 x1, so this is the last place 3 appears
1.451   6
1.802   6
2.551   6
2.591   6 #2.6 in x2 is close to 2.591 x1, so this is the last place 6 appears
3.991  -1
4.321  -1
```

The crux is that the values in `x2` need to be close to the value in `x1` to initiate the change between values within `x3`, not necessarily exactly the same, and added on in `x4`. If the value in `x1` is not close to `x2`, then the values in `x4` don't change between values in `x3`.

Sorry, I hope that makes sense, but if anyone knows how to do that, it'd be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What was the downvote for? Commenting is courteous.

Comment: @Brandon Bertelsen I'm not sure either, was a bit shocked when I saw it was downvoted =/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `cut`

```
x4 <- cut(x1, c(-Inf, x2, Inf), labels = x3, right = FALSE)

x4
# [1] 3  3  6  6  6  6  -1 -1
# Levels: 3 6 -1
```

Beware, the results will be factors.

Should you want to convert them to numeric, you can use:

```
as.numeric(levels(x4))[x4]

# [1]  3  3  6  6  6  6 -1 -1
```

By close, I assumed you meant that the values are in the interval (- Inf to 0.8 ; 0.8 to 2.6 ; 2.6 to Inf)

Comment: That worked beautifully! The only thing I had to change was that `Inf` was changed to `9999` (positive and negative), because for some reason it didn't work with `Inf`. Also, I was dealing with decimal numbers as well, and had to change `x4` to `character()` and then `numeric()`. But worked out in the end, thank you!